# Reading shapefile using C#?

Tags: shapefile, c#

I am new to ArcGIS and trying a few things..

1. I'm trying to read shapefile (which is supplied as an input) using C# and
2. I want to generate a PDF file which contains underlying metadata information (similar to the Identify tool) ?

Comment: According to my knowledge it contains two different questions..

Answer (score 12):

There are multiple options to use when reading `Shapefile` with C#, [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) and [EasyGIS.Net](http://www.easygisdotnet.com/) are already mentioned. **[DotSpatial](https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial)**  is another opensource project. Here is a [tutorial link](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DotSpatial%20Tutorials) as well.

With respect to performance, personally I have found `DotSpatial` doing much better than `SharpMap` with large dataset, and DotSpatial raster support is also excellent.

Comment: dotSpatial @ github https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial

Answer (score 6):

You can try [SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap/) if you want to use LGPL code.

Comment: [SharpMap](https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap) is now on GitHub

Answer (score 3):

This is one nice library [Easy Gis DotNet](http://www.easygisdotnet.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Following are links which will be helpful for you..

Check out the [sample VB code](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IFeatureWorkspace_CreateFeatureClass_Example.htm) ( You can convert VB code to c# using converter)

ESRI forums [link1](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/57436-How-to-create-Shapefile-with-C) [link2](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/3801-C-program-reading-from-shapefile) + [codingcramp blog](http://codingcramp.blogspot.in/2011/07/c-esri-shapefile-reader.html)

Let us know if you have any problem.. thanks

Comment: Now, I want to save "selected feature"(polygon) as image.   How i can achieve that ?